# JFileChooser and Next - Previous Button

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

First of all, I'd like to inform you all that I'm just a beginner and I've tried many thing without any success.

I've managed to make a JFrame then a JPanel and inside that JPanel, a JLabel with icon. I can retrieve the picture with the button `JFileChooser`, the picture is resized to fit the `JLabel`.

My project has exactly 5 files :

- `ImageFilter`: used by `LoadFiles`
- `ImagePreview`: used by `LoadFiles`
- `LoadFiles`: `JFileChooser` class
- `NewJFrame`
- `Utils`: used by `LoadFiles`

I am using NetBeans IDE and the GUI Builder, I made my class LoadFiles(JFileChooser) so that I just have to drop the class on NewJFrame and the button appears on my JFrame, so that my program can be easily modified (Every class is a module, but yet only one which is LoadFiles) and there is nothing except the variable declared in my NewJFrame.

Here is how my program looks like:

[image]

And I want to add two buttons, Next and Previous to navigate between the pictures I already opened in my JLabel.

### Class `LoadFiles`

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LoadFiles extends JButton implements ActionListener {
JFileChooser jfc;

public LoadFiles() {
    super("Load");
    addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        if (jfc == null) {
        jfc = new JFileChooser(".");
        
        jfc.addChoosableFileFilter(new ImageFilter());
        jfc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);            
        jfc.setAccessory(new ImagePreview(jfc));            
        }
         

    jfc.setDialogTitle("test");   
    int result = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        
        File file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println(file.getParent());
        System.out.println(file.getName());
        
        // Read image and place new file icon into preferred locations
        BufferedImage newImage = null;
        try {
            newImage = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("red error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        ImageIcon backgdIcon = new ImageIcon(newImage);
        
        Image zoom = getScaledImage(backgdIcon.getImage(), 471, 189);
        Icon iconScaled = new ImageIcon(zoom);
        NewJFrame.jLabel1.setIcon(iconScaled);
        
    } else if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        System.out.println(JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION);
    }            
}

private Image getScaledImage(Image srcImg, int w, int h){
    BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = resizedImg.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g2.dispose();
    return resizedImg;
}    }
```

You can find here my program:
http://www.speedyshare.com/k6e5r/javaapplication29.7z

Please, could you help me?

Edit 1 - Thank you for your comments, I couldn't answer sooner. I will try what you are talking about both MadProgrammer and Andrew Thompson. I will get back to you later hoping I'll make it work.

I'll also remember for my next posts to make it better (MCVE).

Joop Eggen - I am not trying to make a preview icon in JFileChooser, I already have that. I want to be able to retrieve the last image i added to the JLabel with the Previous Button (not Preview). Thank you anyway for your reply.

Edit 2 - Thank's for your advices mbw, what I had in mind when I did that was thatI could use that classe in any application by just dropping it on a GUI and it could work everywhere by just chaning variable's name but you are right, it is not easy to communicate with the other conponent.

I wanted to do the less code possible in the JFrame, so it can be the most modular possible.

I will probably do like you're saying.

Edit 3 -
Finaly I succeeded,

I declare this in the class :

```
List<BufferedImage> images;
int currentImage = 0;
```

Then after I put the image in the BufferedImage

```
        //bufferedimage dans la arraylist
        if(images == null)
        images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();

        images.add(newImage);
        currentImage = images.size() - 1;
```

And I did two methods

```
public void nextImage() {
    if(images != null && images.get(currentImage + 1) != null )
    {
        ImageIcon backgdIcon = new ImageIcon(images.get(currentImage + 1));
        
        Image zoom = getScaledImage(backgdIcon.getImage(), 471, 189);//taille en pixels
        Icon iconScaled = new ImageIcon(zoom);
        NewJFrame.jLabel1.setIcon(iconScaled);
   }
}

public void prevImage() {
    if(images != null && images.get(currentImage - 1) != null )
    {
        ImageIcon backgdIcon = new ImageIcon(images.get(currentImage - 1));
        
        Image zoom = getScaledImage(backgdIcon.getImage(), 471, 189);//taille en pixels
        Icon iconScaled = new ImageIcon(zoom);
        NewJFrame.jLabel1.setIcon(iconScaled);
    }
}
```

Thank you everyone for all your advices. Have a good day.

Comment: `public class LoadFiles extends JButton..` this is not a good case for extending `JButton`.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example) (here, as opposed to an external site).

Comment: You're going to need some kind of model or list to maintain a reference to the images you've already loaded.  You will need some kind index value to determine which image is meant to be displayed.

Comment: *"I want to add two buttons, Next and Previous to navigate between the pictures I already opened in my `JLabel`."*  As the user loads them, add the `File` objects to an expandable `List` such as `ArrayList<File>`.  Keep an index for the list and the app. knows `currentImage`. For the `<` & `>` buttons, decrement or increment the value and display that image.

Comment: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t49462.html shows how to make a preview in the JFileChooser. That is simplest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some good ideas in the comments, but I think it will be easier if you change the structure of your code.

If I were you, I would not create extend JButton and create a custom class for each button. It really complicates things, and makes it harder to pass information around the gui to different components that need it.

Instead, to make the code easier to read, I would create three JButtons in your JFrame with the netbeans gui builder:  Load, next and previous.  Then you can easily add an action event listener for each button and do the all the work in the JFrame.  This also makes it really easy to keep a reference to all the loaded pictures for the next and previous button to use.